# Printing variables with incrementing suffixes

Tags: variables, python-2.7, increment

What I'm trying to do would be a lot easier to understand by looking at the code:

```
suffix = 1
prefix1="success"
prefix2="success"
prefix3="success"
prefix4="success"
while suffix<5:
    temp = "prefix"+str(suffix)
    print temp
    suffix+=1
```

So what I'm trying to do is to print the value of prefix1, prefix2 etc which is "success" as opposed to "prefix1","prefix2" etc. I fully understand why my code is working how it is, but I want to know if there is a way to print the values of the variables prefix+suffix.

Comment: That's never a good idea. Use a list or dict instead; it's what they're for.

Comment: Yeah, I've got using lists and dictionaries for this purpose down. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a dict would make more sense:

```
d = { 
      'prefix1' : 'success',
      'prefix2' : 'success',
      'prefix3' : 'success',
      'prefix4' : 'success'
    }

for i in range(1,5):
    temp = "prefix%s" % i
    print d[temp]
```

Comment: I don't think that was answering what I was asking, but I just found out about the eval() function which is what I was looking for. If I change:

    temp = "prefix"+str(suffix)

to

    temp = eval("prefix"+str(suffix))

it works and prints "success" multiple times, thank you anyway for a quicker way of doing the loop if I change it to:

    for i in range(1,6):
        print eval("prefix%s" %  str(i))

Comment: Maybe using a dict would suit your needs?  So if `temp` was `"prefix1"`, you want to get its value `"success"`?

Comment: @FraserHislop ... and [you *really* don't want to go playing with `eval()`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), especially if you "just heard about it".

Comment: So eval() is safe as long as I don't eval() user input?

Comment: @FraserHislop if you're asking the question, you don't know how to use `eval()` safely. It's almost always the wrong solution anyway, but if you insist, you can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead.